# MySql how can I fix this category table structure?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a category lookup table with 3 columns
MyISAM Approx 500k rows

```
listing_id          | int(11) 
category_id         | int(11) 
parent_category_id      | int(11)
```

This table is joined on listing when browsing or searching by category.

As parent_category_id is repeated for each category_id when searching on a parent category the query includes

```
 SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT ...
```

to get unique rows and the total number of results found. 
Additionally, we have a range of WHERE and ORDER BY thrown into the mix  (from user filters)

I tried two options;

Remove parent_category_id column and insert unique parents as category_id.
This would enable removing DISTINCT from the query, but as a down side it also increases the amount of rows to scan but i can get a index this way for most common cases.   I've done a test and this seems to work well. Query from 20+ secs to  0.4secs
Or should I create a separate table for parent_category_id.? eg (listing_is, parent_id)

BTW: Listings can have more than one parent and more than 1 category.

What would you recommend?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Normalize parent_category_id into a separate table. The benefits of a smaller index in this case outweigh a single table with more data. Indexes that fit into memory are always faster.